# binance api, i cant put an order with a price in dollar (not in quantity)

Tags: python, python-3.x, binance, binance-api-client

i try to put some orders at a specific price.
For example i would like to put 20 dollars to buy some ETHUSDT at 800 usdt but it gives me this error:

```
binance.exceptions.BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-1106): Parameter 'quoteOrderQty' sent when not required.
```

there is my call function:

```
    buy_order = client.create_order(          
            symbol = "ETHUSDT",
            price = 800,
            quoteOrderQty = 25,
            side = client.SIDE_BUY,
            type = client.ORDER_TYPE_LIMIT,              
            timeInForce = client.TIME_IN_FORCE_GTC)
```

but i dont have any error when i put this :

```
    buy_order = client.create_test_order(symbol="ETHUSDT", side='BUY', type='MARKET', quoteOrderQty=10)
```

to be honnest actually i do that:

```
 def putOrderBuy_at_price(self, symbol, amount, price):
        monney_price = self.client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol=symbol)
    # Calculate how much ETH $200 can buy
        print(monney_price['price'])
        i = 10
        while i != 0:
            try:     
                buy_quantity = round(amount / float(price), i)
                print("-----------", buy_quantity)
                #ETHUSDT
                buy_order = self.client.create_order(          
                    symbol = symbol,
                    price = price,
                    quantity = buy_quantity,
                    side = self.client.SIDE_BUY,
                    type = self.client.ORDER_TYPE_LIMIT,              
                    timeInForce = self.client.TIME_IN_FORCE_GTC)
                break
            except Exception:
                print(i)
                i -= 1
```

And i think there is a better way for that.
Thanks for yours answers

Comment: Please check what `quoteOrderQty` means and what kinds of mandatory parameters needed for each order type in binance API doc.

Answer (score 1):

quoteOrderQty is only for MARKET order.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).